# Speed up PHP rendering HUGE select list

Tags: php, mysql

You guys have been awesome.

My script goes and selects ALL 8500 customers from MYSQL, which in MySQL workbench, takes about **0.16 seconds**, which is fine, but it takes the browser **10 seconds** to render the  box from the results.

**Is there a faster way to create this huge select box?**

I'm stumped because I thought all the PHP was made on the server side and cannot be sped up.

```
<body>
<select name="customer" id="customer" onChange="getcustinfo();" data-placeholder="Choose a Customer" class="chosen-select" style="width:500px;" tabindex="1">
<option value=""></option>
<?php // get the products
    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM `cust`
        LEFT Join `address` 
        ON `cust`.`custid` = `address`.`addcustid`
        and `address`.`addtype` = 'b'
        WHERE `cust`.`custactive` = 'y'"
    ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Query failed: Could not get list of CLIENTS: ' . mysqli_error($con)); // query
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                foreach ($row as $key => $value){ ${$key} = $value; }
                $space="";
                $endingspaces = 4-(2*strlen($prodid));

                $custname = substr($row['custname'],0,15);
                $address1 = substr($row['address1'],0,15);
                $addcity = substr($row['addcity'],0,15);

                print "<option value=\"$custid\">$custid: $space$custname, $address1, $addcity, $addstate</option>";                                                
        }
?>
</select>
</body>
```

Comment: if your list is that large, you might want to consider using something like chosen: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: The time comes from PHP having to load the table into memory and then parse the loop 8500 times to generate the HTML to send out. You may want to rethink selecting all 8500 rows to display. After all, powerful selection tools are one of the major advantages offered by a database. Why throw that utility away?

Answer (score 3):

**Cache it**. Generate that HTML *once* and then save it in memory if you can (APC, memcache) or a flat file. Then on subsequent page loads just read it in from the cache and echo it out. *much* faster.

Comment: out of curiosity, how would you recommend keeping up with changes to the list?

Comment: @joseph4tw Whenever a change is made the cache should be deleted and a new generated. Either automatically or on the next page load. Or the cache can be "refreshed" at a regular interval depending on how important it is for the data to be "fresh" or if it can be stale for a set period of time..

Comment: I agree about how to re-cache it. I was talking more about how to know when the list is changed. The interval idea seems simple enough, but how about when a user creates a new customer and needs to send them an invoice right away (sorry for getting a little off-topic here)?

Comment: *assumption*: customers are managed through a CMS or some  sort of web interface. When the customer is added it can mark the cache as dirty, delete it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Found the problem. Wow.**

**The problem was the "print each option row" function.** I was printing each of the 8500 option values while iterating through the MySQL list. Each row was "printed" to and held in memory, then displayed at the end.

The print option function is apparently actually sending that line to the browser on each iteration, so the select box is not being compiled by the server, but being sent, piece by piece to the browser, taking tons of time.

**I fixed it** by making php create the entire select box on the server (including the opening and closing SELECT tags in a add-to "select_box" variable), then send it as one echo back to the browser when totally done. Now it takes only like 1.2 seconds.

I can live with that.

```
<?php // get the products
    $select_box = "<select name=\"customer\" id=\"customer\" onChange=\"getcustinfo();\" data-placeholder=\"Choose a Customer\" class=\"chosen-select\" style=\"width:227px;\" tabindex=\"1\">
    <option value=\"\"></option>";

    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM `cust`
        LEFT Join `address` 
        ON `cust`.`custid` = `address`.`addcustid`
        and `address`.`addtype` = 'b'
        WHERE `cust`.`custactive` = 'y'"
    ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Query failed: Could not get list of CLIENTS: ' . mysqli_error($con)); // query
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                foreach ($row as $key => $value){ ${$key} = $value; }
                $space="";   
                $custname = substr($row['custname'],0,15);
                $address1 = substr($row['address1'],0,15);
                $addcity = substr($row['addcity'],0,15);

                $select_box .= "<option value=\"$custid\">$custid: $space$custname, $address1, $addcity, $addstate</option>";                                               
        }
    $select_box .="</select>";
    echo $select_box;   
?>
```